# PostgreSQL DBLink: No function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was playing around with DBLINK and I wanted to try it. So I run this simple query

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;

SELECT *  
FROM dblink(('dbname=genesis_admin')::text,
      ('SELECT * FROM user_account')::text);
```

then to my surprise

```
[WARNING  ] CREATE EXTENSION dblink
            ERROR:  extension "dblink" already exists
[WARNING  ] SELECT *  FROM dblink(('dbname=genesis_admin')::text, ('SELECT * FROM user_account')::text)
            ERROR:  function dblink(text, text) does not exist
            LINE 1: SELECT *  FROM dblink(('dbname=genesis_admin')::text, ('SELE...
                                   ^
            HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can it not be existing if it already exists?

Comment: Not a Postgres user, but have a look here: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html - this seems to imply you're doing it wrong. the CREATE EXTENSION is soing something else, and then using dbLink (which is an extension) is not what you think it is.

Comment: Might be installed into a schema which is not in your current search path. Try `SELECT oid::regprocedure FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'dblink'`, see if it comes out with a namespace qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error and the reason is that this is because `DBLink` gets installed (by default) in Public schema and you have probably modified the search_path to a list that doesn't include public). The Database although contains the function `DBlink(text, text)` is therefore unable to find that function.

To get this to work, you need to add specific schema to the `DBlink` function call.

```
SELECT public.dblink(xxx, yyy);
```